# How to find current across a resistor using Thevenin Theorem

Tags: current, resistors, dc, thevenin

It's my first question here. How to find the current through 3 ohm resistor using Thevenin theorem?[image]

Comment: What have you figured out so far?

Comment: @CamilStaps 1. Removed the 3ohm resistor.
2. Converted the left most current source into voltage source.
3. Assumed the current I to be flowing clockwise.
4. Made an eqn. 25-5I-10I-10-2I+20=0
5. I = 2.05 amp
6. Then considered the right loop to make another eqn. Vth-2I+20=0
then Vth= -15.9v
7. Rth = 30/17 ohm
8. and and I through 3 comes out to be 9.01 amp which is wrong.

Comment: How do you know it's wrong? Does the answers book also provide an explanation? If so, what don't you understand? If not, did you try following the instructions of your textbook?

Comment: The given ans is 3.33 amp.

Comment: Does the answers book also provide an explanation? If so, what don't you understand? If not, did you try following the instructions of your textbook?

Comment: Its coming out 3.34 A only. Calculations error. Till step 7 ok. Rth = 1.76 ohm, Vth = 15.9 V. So I = 15.9 / (1.76 + 3) = 3.34 A

Comment: Why you have to use Thevenin’s theorem? This problem requires superposition theorem.

Comment: Note that the question as asked is idiotic (your rewording is fine.)  Current is through the resistor.  Voltage would be across the resistor.

Answer (score 3):

I will solve it the easy way, given that the question didn't mention using a specific method. Note that I will be following some notation:

- CS to denote a Current Source
- VS to denote a Voltage Source

Moreover, notice that we will be do NOTHING to 3 ohm resistance in our approach to find the current, hence we will be manipulating the branches on the right and left only without touching that resistance.

$$$$

---

$$$$

**Source Transformation** (the easy approach):

1. Change the left most parallel CS-Resistance into series VS-Resistance; keeping in mind that in voltage sources (emfs), current is generated, and *hence it enters from the -ve polarity and leaves from the +ve polarity. (This is the opposite of course for power dissipating elements.)

   [image]
2. Add the VSs-Resistance in the left branch of the circuit.

   [image]
3. Change the left and right branches series VS-Resistance combinations into parallel CS-Resistance ones. 
   Note that the left CS will be pointing upward, while the right one is in the opposite direction (check the note in step 2).

   [image]
4. Combine the CSs, and resistances. **(Sorry it is 30/17; typo.)**

   [image]
5. Find the current using current divider rule.

   [image]

Answer (score 0):

first you should obtain Thevenin equivalent from 2 point of 3ohm resistor in fact in this step you should ignore resistor itself and remove it from circuit,then instead resistor 
you put an voltage source(or current source never mind) V and then calculate V by I(current of voltage source) then you have V=aI+b that a is Thevnin equivalent's resistor and b is Thevenin equivalent's voltage now instead of circuit you put a voltge source b and resistor a then stick it with 3ohm resistor and obtain its current.
(Sorry for my bad English)